# derived class has same member variable name as base class

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
protected:
    int m_nValue;
public:
    A(int nValue):m_nValue(nValue)
    {
        cout << m_nValue << endl;
    }
};
class B: public A
{
public:
    B(int nValue): A(m_nValue)
    {
        cout << m_nValue << endl;
    }
    int getValue()
    {
        return m_nValue;
    }
};
int main()
{
    B b(4);
    cout << b.getValue() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here, in the above program I am not declaring `m_nValue` again in the Derived class. In the output, I see only junk values getting displayed rather than displaying value "4".
Please explain this.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to initialize `m_nValue` with `m_nValue` itself. The parameter `nValue` (passed in the value `4`) is not used at all. That's why `m_nValue` has only garbage value.

You might want

```
B(int nValue): A(nValue)
{
    cout << m_nValue << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
B(int nValue): A(nValue)
```

You should initialize `A` with `nValue` rather than `m_nValue`

Answer (score 2):

Your constructor is bugged `B(int nValue): A(m_nValue)`. You are not using `nValue` to pass it to `A` constructor but the instance variable which is uninitialized.